# Trouble Authenticating with WP remote login request

Tags: vb.net, wordpress, login-control

Okay so I was going to post this on the last 3 errors I got, but I fixed those all(thankfully). I no longer get any kind of cookie blocked message, however now I get a Error logging in whether I'm putting in the correct password or an invalid one. I think its either
A. a cookie storage error.
B. or a problem with redirection.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim logincookie As CookieContainer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         Handles Button1.Click
    Dim postData As String = "log=" & TextBox1.Text & "&pwd=" & TextBox2.Text & "wp-  submit=Log+In&redirect_to=""http://csvlife.com/wp-admin/" & "&wordpress_test_cookie=1"
    Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer()
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://csvlife.com/wp-login.php"), HttpWebRequest)
    postreq.Method = "POST"
    postreq.KeepAlive = True
    postreq.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
    postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b6pre) Gecko/20100903 Firefox/4.0b6pre"
    postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postreq.Referer = "http://csvlife.com/wp-login.php"
    postreq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postreq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempcookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    If thepage.Contains("ERROR") Then
        MsgBox("Error logging in!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Lets Start Blogging!")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I have my fiddler open and I've logged into the page and noticed that when I login regularly from by regular browser
fiddler will show this: 
[image]
then the results come in and it looks like this:
[image]
**Clarification: The pictures above is what the web traffic info looks like when I login from any basic browser on my computer**

Here is what it looks like what I login from the program: 
[image]
Always an error.
[image]
And the request number is just 200 no 302 before or after.

However when I try through my program the req number always remains 200 which is post. Its like it never gets to redirect and I don't know why. Notes: This is my website and this not for any kind of malware or whatever. Its just for blog automation. If there was anything else I could find on this matter I would. At this point I have no other option. Thank you kindly for your help and consideration.

Comment: The 200 response code is the http server response (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - a 200 should be good. The above appears to show a successful redirect (302) to the "wp-admin" directory.

Comment: This is the results of me logging in through Chrome, not through the program that I created.  And what I mean by 200 is this: when the req goes through its supposed to goto 302 redirect to wp-admin then show 200 instead it just shows 200. I will add more. I can see how it can look confusing.

Comment: Have you examined the html returned with the last 200? What is the content of the page?

Comment: @Paxic yes: I see it in the webview of fiddler. It says ERROR: The password you entered for the username csvlife is incorrect.However i have changed my password(to really simple things like password) and it still doesn't work. Logging in Chrome works fine. I think its a redirect error but I'm not sure.

Comment: In your code above you have encoded the post parameters in "postData". I do not see postData being passed to the server anywhere.

Comment: Yes its passed on with byteData. Do you see it in the code? Its right at the top: Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData) sorry I looked at it again. byteData breaks the credentials down and then  postreqstream.Write passes it to the server.

Comment: You are quite right - I misunderstood how that worked.

Comment: Have you looked at the value stored in 'byteData' to see if it is what you expect? I am not a .net programmer and am not sure about the assignment used.

Comment: I think you could be right. I'm going to look at fiddler and maybe open WireShark to see exactly whats being sent. It may jumble it all together meaning the username and the password.

Comment: No its breaking it down correctly. Username shows up in its place as well as password. I can see this in the syntax/text view.

Comment: is there a missing ampersand in the post request? There is no separator between the end of the password parameter and the next string.

Comment: Are you looking at line 9? I see a & between the pwd and login! EDIT TO ADD: YOU BEAUTIFUL MAN CHILD YOU!!! LET ME FIRST MAKE SURE. It works!

Comment: Yes it works all. How do I mark this as completed and answered?

Comment: yes, line nine. I'm looking at the string content and not the code. I see the ampersand that separates the log parameter from pwd and then it looks to me like the piece of text is appended to the end of the password value: "&pwd=" & TextBox2.Text & "wp-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 9:

Dim postData As String = "log=" & TextBox1.Text & "&pwd=" & TextBox2.Text & "wp-  submit=Log+In&redirect_to=""http://csvlife.com/wp-admin/" & "&wordpress_test_cookie=1"

The parameters to be sent with the post need to be separated with an ampersand, as written the password parameter has "wp-  submit=Log+In&redirect_to=http://csvlife.com/wp-admin/" appended to it.

Assuming  wp is a parameter:
Dim postData As String = "log=" & TextBox1.Text & "&pwd=" & TextBox2.Text & "&wp-  submit=Log+In&redirect_to=""http://csvlife.com/wp-admin/" & "&wordpress_test_cookie=1"